# missing seal on Geberit UP200 system between braided hose and fill valve

Tags: seal, cistern

I've recently descaled the flush and fill valve to solve a leaking problem on my Geberit UP200 concealed cistern, however when I reassembled everything, there is now a leak between the braided hose and fill valve.  I noticed online that there should be a seal, which I must have lost in the process.  It's quite frustrating because I managed to fix the original problem, but created a new one in the process.

I can see that Geberit has a part number 240.922.00.1, but I cannot source this in Denmark.  Does anyone have specs on this seal and can recommend a generic replacement?

[image: this is from a video I found online with the seal that I'm missing]

Many thanks.

Comment: check all other connections ... one of them may have two seals

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm just wondering if someone knows the dimensions of the missing seal, so I can find a generic replacement.  Otherwise, perhaps I should reword the question to ask how to determine the replacement of a seal where you don't know what the dimensions of the original seal was.